# Cassandra load distribution - uneven 1.2.8

Tags: cassandra, ycsb

I am running a 4 node cluster setup of apache-cassandra-1.2.8 and trying to load about 25 million records. The cluster is setup with the default (murmur) partitioning and assigned tokens based on the algorithm provided [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html)

The nodetool displays the ring configuration as below:

> [root@node1 apache-cassandra-1.2.8]# bin/nodetool -host
>   10.5.50.250 -p 7199 ring
>
> Datacenter: datacenter1
>   ========== Replicas: 1
>
> Address    Rack        Status State   Load            Owns          Token
>                                                                               -461168601842738790
>   127.0.0.1  rack1       Up     Normal  6.29 GB         25.00%              4611686018427387904
>   127.0.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  613.9 MB        2.50%               0
>   127.0.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  6.29 GB         25.00%              -9223372036854775808
>   127.0.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  12.13 GB        47.50%              -461168601842738790

As you can see, the load is not being distributed evenly (25% on each node). Is my assumption about the murmur protocol wrong here or is my setup not configured properly?

Any insights on how to get good load balancing with the now default murmur partitioning which is claimed to be faster than the previously default random partitioner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the token for 127.0.0.4 has a digit missing from the end, it should be `-4611686018427387904`.

You should also look at using virtual nodes, since it gives you load balancing without calculating tokens and there's no need to rebalanced after scaling your cluster.